# What does the `<<` (double less than) mean without an argument?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, formtastic

I found this inside a method I want to override in the formtastic Gem. The method looks like:

```
def to_html
  input_wrapping do
    hidden_field_html <<
    label_with_nested_checkbox
  end
end
```

What does the `<<` do on the third line? I know what it does with Arrays  but here I have no idea.

Comment: `hidden_field_html` should be an `array` or `string` and the `label_with_nested_checkbox` is being added into it. The standard says that your code should not exceed 80 columns so may be due to that it has been written in two lines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can read it like this:

```
hidden_field_html << label_with_nested_checkbox
```

`label_with_nested_checkbox` is the argument being concatenated onto the end of `hidden_field_html` - they've split it over two lines for 'clarity'

Comment: The 4th line should probably be indented 2 spaces, at least, that's what I'd do.

Answer (score 1):

1. In class inheritance there is `<` used, not `<<`, and the former has nothing to do with method `<<` in general.
2. Ruby has a high level of tolerance to space indenting; almost everywhere one might put any amount of spaces, including newlines, between function call and it’s argument.

E. g.:

```
'aaa'.
  length
#⇒ 3
```

and

```
'aaa'
  .length
#⇒ 3
```

are both perfectly valid.

3. `<<` is the generic method, that might be overwritten in any class. Here it is supposedly [`String#<<`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-3C-3C) method, that *inplace appending* the argument to the string receiver.

In general, one might overwrite this method in any arbitrary class:

```
class A
  attr_accessor :var
  def initialize
    @var = 5
  end
  def << value
    @var += value
  end
end

a = A.new
a.var
#⇒ 5
a << 37
a.var
#⇒ 42
```

Comment: So they use their custom `<<`-method? Thanks! :)

Comment: No, as I have said, they supposedly use `String#<<`. You might check this by examining the receiver class: `puts hidden_field_html.class.to_s`.